# How to install android constraint layout tools outside of Android Studio by using the command line?

Tags: android

I'm manually installing an Android-Gradle build server which means that I'm not using Android Studio SDK but instead using the `android update sdk` command to install the required tools.

I was able to install most of the packages which are required for the build to finish successfully but there are some tools which I'm unable to find:

```
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha(1-4)
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha(1-4)
```

Following @CommonsWare comment, here's the output of the build (which shows that the tools are being looked for at the repositories automatically but not found:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Company'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Company:_productionDebugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.jar
         http://dl.bintray.com/optimizely/optimizely/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.pom
         http://dl.bintray.com/optimizely/optimizely/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.jar
         file:/Users/itai/work_repos/Company-Android_fork/.gradle/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.pom
         file:/Users/itai/work_repos/Company-Android_fork/.gradle/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.jar
         file:/Users/itai/work_repos/Company-Android_fork/.gradle/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.pom
         file:/Users/itai/work_repos/Company-Android_fork/.gradle/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-alpha4/constraint-layout-1.0.0-alpha4.jar
     Required by:
         Company-Android_fork:Company:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.163 secs
```

Any idea how they can be installed manually (not through Android Studio)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Create a project that has those dependencies. Make your SDK installation world-writeable. Build the project. The build process will automatically download those dependencies, or it will tell you that you need to copy over a license file to the build server (along with a link to instructions to do that). See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128) for more.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the output of the build, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest Android Plugin for Gradle. Also, try `alpha7`, as I don't know if `alpha4` is available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now you can install it through command line:

```
your_sdk_location/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, fixed my jenkins config, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible without Android Studio 2.2 Beta yet, but if you have it somewhere, then you just need to copy the m2repository from your `sdk/extras` to your project `sdk/extras` folder.

So if you have your project built in an Android Studio:

1. check the project's sdk location (File/Project Structure : SDK location).
2. go to your_sdk_location/extras folder and copy m2repository
3. paste the folder to your existing project's sdk/extras folder.
4. rebuild your project.

Comment: Oh man, thats is a good way to get into trouble with version issues. Too bad its the only way at the moment. Although I suppose you could push to an artifact repository and pick them up there.

Comment: That's absolutley true if you find any better solution please don't hasitate to share with me also! :)